# Detect SIM card change on Android Q 10

Tags: android

There are many of questions/answers on how to detect if the user as changed or not is SIM but many of them rely on obtaining the SIM card imsi (`TelephonyManager.getSubscriberId()`) and since this info is no longer available (https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#non-resettable-device-ids), on Android Q/10 how can we detect that the user changed is SIM?

Comment: This is a nice article explaining how to implement it with Subscriber IDs and broadcast receivers - https://faanghut.com/detecting-sim-change-on-android/

Answer (score 2):

Check this [mobile service subscriptions](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids#mobile-service-subscriptions).
Based on the given description, every new sim card should receive a new int number `SubscriptionId`, unique per device, until it gets factory reset.

```
var subscriptionManager = getSystemService(SubscriptionManager::class.java)
subscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList()
SubscriptionInfo.getSubscriptionId()
```

Comment: This sounds promising. However, how would you tweak this for a dual sim device?

Comment: It works with dual sim. You will then receive a list of ids.