# Android 11 - how to detect programmatically when a SIM is inserted?

Tags: android-11, sim-card

I am trying to catch an event in Android 11 that would get triggered when a SIM card is inserted in a phone. The following question mentions how to fetch the unique subscription ID, to know if the SIM is changed but it does not address how to catch that event of SIM insertion.
[Detect SIM card change on Android Q 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58268038/detect-sim-card-change-on-android-q-10)

```
var subscriptionManager = getSystemService(SubscriptionManager::class.java)
subscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList()
SubscriptionInfo.getSubscriptionId()
```

Please let me know the right approach to handle SIM insertion event. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an event/callback for SIM insertion, the best way you can do this is with broadcast receivers.

```
class SimChangeReceivers: BroadcastReceiver() {
    private val TAG = "SimChangeReceivers"

    // This is where you'll be receiving the SIM_STATE_CHANGE intent.
    override fun onReceive(p0: Context?, p1: Intent?) {
        var state = ""
        if (p1 != null) {
            state = p1.extras?.getString("ss").toString()
            if (state == "LOADED")
                Log.i(TAG, "SIM Insertion Detected")
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "SIM State Change Detected $state")
    }
}
```

Make sure, that you add this receiver in your manifest, along with the READ_PHONE_STATE permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
....
        <receiver android:name=".SimChangeReceivers"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

You can consider when `state` to be either `READY` or `LOADED` as SIM insertion.

Check out [this](https://faanghut.com/detecting-sim-change-on-android/) article on Faanghut, which talks about getting an intent for **SIM_STATE_CHANGED**. Hope this helps, if you any concerns regarding this, do let me know.