# How to detect Sim change in Android device?

Tags: android, kotlin

Is there any way to know if the user has changed his SIM card with a different SIM card?

In my Project require to checking simcard is change or not in android.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a duplicate question. Check this link below:

[Detect SIM card change on Android Q 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58268038/detect-sim-card-change-on-android-q-10)